Scala Fs2: Aggregate computation on infinite streams
I cant seem to understand how to perform aggregate computations on infinite streams. Taking an infinite stream of elements and performing a computation on each one individually is easy, but collecting several and performing an aggregate computation seems impossible.
I'm using scala and Fs2, but this is probably applicable to any infinite streaming library.
Lets say you've got an infinite stream of events with some timestamp attached
Stream[F, Event]
where event is
case class Event(time: Instant, data: Json)
We want to perform some simple analysis on the events per minute - perhaps counting the number, but the computation itself is trivial. Lets assume we have an existing function
def analyse: List[Event] => Result
Where Result is just a string wrapper storing the output of some unknown analysis
case class Result(v: String)
If my understanding is correct we need to define a Pipe
Pipe[F, Event, Result]
I can't wrap my head around how this works with infinite streams, nor figure out how to implement it.
Logically my head suggests splitting the stream up into finite streams of Events in each hour, converting it to a list and then passing that off to the analyse function but the splitting of an infinite stream feels illogical, as if you were to keep segmenting an infinite stream it would never end.

You can't aggregate all the data of an infinite stream, but you can create a stream of aggregates, each representing the aggregate of a portion of the original stream (where portion might mean a fixed number of items or a time windows, for example). E.g. if you have a stream that starts with the items [1, 2, 3, 4, ... you can't calculate its average, but you might want to say that you will compute the average every 2 items and return it, generating the stream [1.5, 3.5, ....

Check the Scaladoc of fs2: https://www.javadoc.io/doc/co.fs2/fs2-docs_2.13/3.10.2/fs2/Stream.html - There are plenty of methods to get the results you want like: chunkN, split, groupAdjacentBy, groupWithin.

Since your aim is to perform analysis on events that happened every minute, you should probably start by establishing some kind of boundary event to denote the start/end of each buffer period. You can use Stream.awakeEvery(finiteDuration) to create a stream that emits an event at a regular interval. You can then use Stream#either to merge that with your event stream, to get a Stream[F, Either[Event, FiniteDuration]].
From there, probably the easiest way would be to use Stream#scan or Stream#evalScan to fold in some state, e.g.
val events: Stream[F, Event] = ???
def analyze(buffer: List[Event]): Result = ???

// an event buffer, and an optional value to emit
type ScanState = (List[Event], Option[Result])

val analyzedEvents: Stream[F, Result] = events
  .either(Stream.awakeEvery[F](1.minute))
  .scan[ScanState](Nil -> None) { 
    case ((buffer, _), Left(event)) =>
      // add the event to the buffer (in reverse order for O(1) prepend)
      (event :: buffer, None)
    case ((buffer, _), Right(timerTick)) =>
      // perform analysis, clear buffer, emit result
      val result = analyze(buffer.reverse)
      (Nil, Some(result))
  }
  .unNone // omit `None`s to just emit plain `Result`

There's also the Pull interface of streams, which you could use in place of scan to implement finer-grained control over how you consume the input and emit outputs. See https://fs2.io/#/guide?id=transforming-streams-using-pulls for an intro to that.
Note that if your awakeEvery duration goes up, the potential size of your event buffer will up, so you will want to take that into consideration with how you decide to build and clear your buffer.

Is there a way to makes sure you have the entire data for a unit of time that you process the aggregates for, assuming that the event contains a date/time field (time in the OPs post)?

To me it looks like whenever you wake up you need to collect the latest data (save it somewhere for later processing) and/or compute the aggregates for the time units (let's say an hour) that you have all the data for and haven't been processed yet.

@boggy I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding your question, or you're misunderstanding my answer. In my example, the data during any given window is being collected in buffer; when a new event is seen, it is added to the buffer, and when the timer wakes up, you analyze the contents of the buffer. There's no extra "collect the latest data" step, as that's already done.

My point is whenever the timer wakes up, you get the data, but that data could stretch over two units of time that you'd need to aggregate. Let's say, the process wake up at 05s of the minute, you might get some records from the previous minute and you might get some records in the current minute. Obviously if you want to aggregate the data from the previous minute, it has to be all somewhere. And you cannot aggregate the data yet for the current minute because it is not over yet.

Of course all this logic has to be implemented in the handler. But I was just curious if you can fire an event when there is a data in change in the stream data. For instance, if you have a timestamp in your data, if the minute of the timestamp changes then you fire some event with all the records since the last data change.

In your answer you said: you should probably start by establishing some kind of boundary event to denote the start/end of each buffer period. Can this boundary be derived based on the data in the stream, for example, when a value of a function based on the data changes? That function can be minute of timestamp or hour of timestamp

"if you can fire an event when there is a data in change in the stream data" -- You could use Stream#zipWithPrevious to perform some logic based on a comparison of the previous and "current" event. With that approach, you might even avoid the awakeEvery

@boggy that sounds like groupAdjacentBy
